# Remove from String Array what is in List

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a String Array x and a List y and I want to remove all data from Y from the List X, how to do that in the fastest way?

e.g.:
X:
1) "aaa.bbb.ccc"
2) "ddd.eee.fff"
3) "ggg.hhh.jjj"

Y:
1) "bbb"
2) "fff"

Result should be a new List in Which only 3) exist because X.1 gets deleted by Y.1 and X.2 gets deleted by Y.2

How to do that?

I know I could do a foreach on the List X and check with everything in List Y, bit is that the fastest way?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to remove from x all elements which contain as substrings any of the elements of y? Also: You say "Array", do you mean "List"?

Comment: Should X1 also be removed if Y1 was only "bb"?

Comment: Yes, it should be cross references.

Comment: @Kovu Do you mean "Yes, if the thing to remove is "bb" then you should remove the "aaa.bbb.ccc" item"? (Even though "bb" is only a subset of "bbb")

Answer (score 9):

The most *convenient* would be

```
var Z = X.Where(x => !x.Split('.').Intersect(Y).Any()).ToList();
```

That is not the same as "fastest". Probably the *fastest* (runtime) way to do that is to use a token search, like:

```
public static bool ContainsToken(string value, string token, char delimiter = '.')
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) return false;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return false;

    int lastIndex = -1, idx, endIndex = value.Length - token.Length, tokenLength = token.Length;
    while ((idx = value.IndexOf(token, lastIndex + 1)) > lastIndex)
    {
        lastIndex = idx;
        if ((idx == 0 || (value[idx - 1] == delimiter))
            && (idx == endIndex || (value[idx + tokenLength] == delimiter)))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

then something like:

```
var list = new List<string>(X.Length);
foreach(var x in X)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach(var y in Y)
    {
        if(ContainsToken(x, y, '.'))
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) list.Add(x);
}
```

This:

- doesn't allocate arrays (for the output of `Split`, of for the `params char[]` of `Split`)
- doesn't create any new `string` instances (for the output of `Split`)
- doesn't use delegate abstraction
- doesn't have captured scopes
- uses the `struct` custom iterator of `List<T>` rather than the `class` iterator of `IEnumerable<T>`
- starts the new `List<T>` with the appropriate worst-case size to avoid reallocations

Comment: @DeeMac see edit, which avoids things like allocations due to `Split`

Comment: +1 then. Interesting to see your code on token search, I  haven't seen that before.

Comment: @DeeMac it is actually taken from some stackoverflow.com code I was writing yesterday to replace some code that was looking for matches in the form `"abc;def;ghij"` - the old code was doing a `Split`, and we were seeing lots of overhead from repeated strings (and arrays) slowly filling memory - i.e. **every** request would cause an extra `"abc"`, `"def"`, `"ghij"`, and a new `string[3]`. On stackoverflow.com, that fills up quickly...

Comment: Given your `ContainsToken()` then I think you can use it to remove all the matching items from the list like so: `x.RemoveAll(s1 => y.Any(s2 => ContainsToken(s1, s2, '.')));` (if you want the original list to be modified)

Comment: @MatthewWatson well, the question stated "a new list"; also, I was trying to avoid **any** invisible allocations (such as a capture context) - but yes: that's a nice usage of `RemoveAll`

Comment: If X1 ("aaa.bbb.ccc") should also be removed if Y1 was only "bb", then there is no need for the delimiter, right?

Comment: @Corak yes, if `bb` would cause `aaa.bbb.ccc` to be removed, you could just use a string contains check; the original question is unclear on this, IMO

Comment: @Corak I'd agree with that. But to be honest I would reject such a wooly spec as the one in the OP if I was given it at work. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over X and Y would indeed be the fastest option because you have this *Contains* constraint. I really don't see any other way.

It should **not** be a `foreach` over X though, because you cannot modify the collection you iterate over with `foreach`.

So an option would be:

```
for (int counterX = 0; counterX < X.Length; counterX++)
{
    for(int counterY = 0; counterY < Y.Length; counterY++)
    {
        if (X[counterX].Contains(Y[counterY]))
        {
            X.RemoveAt(counterX--);
            counterY = Y.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

This should do it (mind you, this code is not tested).

Comment: I've proposed the same answer but got down-voted!? +1 for your answer, it's what I agree would be the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a fairly fast approach would be to use List's built-in `RemoveAll()` method:

```
List<string> x = new List<string>
{
    "aaa.bbb.ccc",
    "ddd.eee.fff",
    "ggg.hhh.jjj"
};

List<string> y = new List<string>
{
    "bbb",
    "fff"
};

x.RemoveAll(s => y.Any(s.Contains));
```

(Note that I am assuming that you have two lists, x and y. Your OP mentions a string array but then goes on to talk about "List X" and "List Y", so I'm ignoring the string array bit.)

Comment: Contains here is unreliable because "aaa.bbbb.ccc" contains "bbb", but I wouldn't consider that a "match"

Comment: @MarcGravell The OP is ambiguous in this regard. As you can see, I asked for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using `Aggregate` function

```
    var xArr = new string[] { "aaa.bbb.ccc", "ddd.eee.fff", "ggg.hhh.jjj" };
    var yList = new List<string> { "bbb", "fff" };

    var result = xArr.Aggregate(new List<string> { }, (acc, next) =>
    {
        var elems = next.Split('.');
        foreach (var y in yList)
            if (elems.Contains(y))
                return acc;
        acc.Add(next);
        return acc;
    });
```

Comment: That's a whole lot of `Split`s... if the aim is *convenience*, it can be done in one line; if the aim is *performance*, then: there are better approaches

Comment: @MarcGravell, thanks, I improved the answer for doing just one split per iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a relatively small list the performance ramifications wouldn't really be a big deal. This is the simplest foreach solution I could come up with.

```
List<string> ListZ = ListX.ToList();

foreach (string x in ListX)
{
    foreach (string y in ListY)
    {
        if (x.Contains(y))
            ListZ.Remove(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: This gets a little tricky - if `Y` has `"bbb"`, does that cause `"aaa.bbbbb.ccc"`, to be removed? well, it *would* - but should it? (this is perhaps more a question for the OP)